# Extract List from Lists and Print each List with a new format - Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have a list in the following format, including the extra square brackets on the ends:

```
[[[['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B'], ['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B'], ['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']]]]
```

I would like to take this list and print out the following:

```
10.0.0.0-E - 10.0.0.0-B

172.0.0.0-E - 172.0.0.0-B

12.0.0.0-E - 12.0.0.0-B
```

Are the extra brackets screwing me up?

I've tried this..

```py
newList = []
for item in result:
    newList.append(item[0].split(","))
print(newList)
```

Comment: Please share the errors that you have found. From what I have seen here, you should not use ```.split(",")``` because you have a nested list, not a string that contains commas. The ```.split(",")``` will split a string that contains commas.

Comment: There's no "extra square brackets", you have a list of one element, which is a list of one element, which is a list of one element, which is a list of three elements, all of which are lists of two elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is a list inside a list inside a list, which explains the extra brackets.

This works:

```
result = [[[['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B'], ['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B'], ['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']]]]

for item in result[0][0]:
    print(f'{item[0]} - {item[1]}')
```

`result[0][0]` selects the first element of `result`, a list, and then selects its first element, another list - the for loop then assigns each element of that list to `item` one at a time.

`print(f'{item[0]} - {item[1]}')` takes that item and prints a formatted string like you need:

```
10.0.0.0-E - 10.0.0.0-B
172.0.0.0-E - 172.0.0.0-B
12.0.0.0-E - 12.0.0.0-B
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the inner list is always a pair of string:

```
from functools import reduce
a = [[[['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B'], ['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B'], ['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']]]]

if a:
    while type(a[0]) == list:
        a = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,a)

for i in range(0,len(a),2):
    print(a[i],a[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps my friend:

```
a = [[[['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B'], ['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B'], ['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']]]]
main_list = a[0][0]
for i in range(len(main_list)):
    print(main_list[i][0], '-' ,main_list[i][1])
```

Output:

```
10.0.0.0-E - 10.0.0.0-B
172.0.0.0-E - 172.0.0.0-B
12.0.0.0-E - 12.0.0.0-B
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to loop through the specified index something like this

```
for i in x[0][0]:                                                                                                      
    print(i) 

Result                                                                                                                                                                                            
['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B']                                                                                            
['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B']                                                                                          
['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']
```

or you could of course use **end=''** like this example

```
 for i in x[0][0]:
    for j in I:                                                                                                       
        print(j, end='')                                                                                               
    print(end='\n')                                                                                                   
 
 Result:
  10.0.0.0-E10.0.0.0-B                                                                                                    
  172.0.0.0-E172.0.0.0-B                                                                                                  
  12.0.0.0-E12.0.0.0-B
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help.  This is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So you basically have nested lists in four levels:

```
[ # <- first level
    [ # <- second level
        [ # <- third level
            ['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B'],
            ['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B'],
            ['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']
        ]
    ]
]
```

The first and second levels are not important in this case. You want to iterate over the third level and join the strings.

Start by removing those two outer levels:

```
my_list = [[[['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B'], ['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B'], ['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']]]]
list_of_pairs = my_list[0][0]
```

and then you iterate over `list_of_pairs` using `for pair in list_of_pairs` and join the strings:

```
for pair in list_of_pairs:
    print(' - '.join(pair))
```

Putting it all together:

```
my_list = [[[['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B'], ['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B'], ['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']]]]

for pair in my_list[0][0]:
    print(' - '.join(pair))
```

Or, getting rid of the explicit for-loop:

```
my_list = [[[['10.0.0.0-E', '10.0.0.0-B'], ['172.0.0.0-E', '172.0.0.0-B'], ['12.0.0.0-E', '12.0.0.0-B']]]]

print('\n'.join(' - '.join(pair) for pair in my_list[0][0]))
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this is extremely helpful to me for building my foundational knowledge. Really appreciate the help.